# Handling posted data

Tags: node.js, post, axios

I have two Servers(A and B).I post a data with axios from the server A to B and console.log it in the other server, but the data is not in the posted message from server A.

Server A:

```
var http = require('http')
var axios = require('axios')

const data = {name: 'karo', age: 18, email: 'karoakhgar82@hotmail.com'}

http.createServer(function(req, res){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'application\json'})
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data))
        

}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1')

const api = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:1338'})
api.post('/', {
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(res => {
     console.log(res)
})
.catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
})
```

Server B :

```
var http = require('http')

http.createServer(function(req, res){
        console.log(req);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'})
        res.end('hello world')

}).listen(1338,'127.0.0.1')
```

I also tried http request and its the same

Comment: Is this really 2 servers? Looks like you have 1 instance (localhost) and trying to send data from one port to another port. In my opinion, it should have 2 different ip addresses.

Comment: tried that and the problem didn't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log res.data instead of res

```
api.post('/', {
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(res => {
     //log res.data instead of res
     console.log(res.data)
})
.catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
})
```

If you want to log th data received from server A in server B:

`npm i body` in server B dir.
server B:

```
var http = require('http');

var anyBody = require("body/any")

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    anyBody(req, res, {}, (err,data)=>{console.log(data)});
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
    res.end('hello world')

}).listen(1338,'127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: no I want the data in server B

Answer (score 0):

The request object `req` does *not* contain the request body as a string, because the body is *streamed* by the client. Writing it into a string would mean waiting for the stream to finish, before the request handler can start building the response object `res`. But that would be very inflexible.

The following code instructs the request handler to wait for the body and then log it:

```js
http.createServer(async function(req, res) {
  var body = "";
  for await (var chunk of req) body += chunk.toString();
  console.log(body);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
  res.end('hello world')
});
```